# Other ways "Fossil fuels" can form

Tags: science-based, fuels, oil

For clarification my question is: What are some other ways hydrocarbons can form?

Okay for context in my world people traveled to another planet and found hydrocarbons in the ground (coal, oil and natural gases). This sort of implies that life lived on this planet very long ago and the media greatly promote this story.
But in reality there is a scientific explanation for how hydrocarbons formed on this planet that does not include alien life and is discovered later.

So what are some other ways "fossil fuels" could form on this planet without organisms? To me it feels like there should be many other ways for such simple molecules to form in natural ways without carbon based lifeforms. But I haven't really found anything.

Comment: have you done any research on your own? What have you found? Also, please read the tag wiki and apply what it says.

Comment: "To me it feels like there should be many other ways for such simple molecules to form in natural ways without carbon based lifeforms." Great, enlighten us! And read up on the use of commas, they are our friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a web search on "oil origin theories" you will find decent answers to your question.

This is what Wikipedia says about the [abiogenic theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenic_petroleum_origin):

> The abiogenic petroleum origin hypothesis proposes that most of earth's petroleum and natural gas deposits were formed inorganically. Scientific evidence overwhelmingly supports a biogenic origin for most of the worlds petroleum deposits.
>
> - **Primordial deposits**: Thomas Gold's work was focused on hydrocarbon deposits of primordial origin. Meteorites are believed to represent the major composition of material from which the Earth was formed. Some meteorites, such as carbonaceous chondrites, contain carbonaceous material. If a large amount of this material is still within the Earth, it could have been leaking upward for billions of years. The thermodynamic conditions within the mantle would allow many hydrocarbon molecules to be at equilibrium under high pressure and high temperature. Although molecules in these conditions may disassociate, resulting fragments would be reformed due to the pressure. An average equilibrium of various molecules would exist depending upon conditions and the carbon-hydrogen ratio of the material.
> - **Creation within the mantle**: Russian researchers concluded that hydrocarbon mixes would be created within the mantle. Experiments under high temperatures and pressures produced many hydrocarbons—including n-alkanes through C10H22—from iron oxide, calcium carbonate, and water. Because such materials are in the mantle and in subducted crust, there is no requirement that all hydrocarbons be produced from primordial deposits.
> - **Hydrogen generation**: Hydrogen gas and water have been found more than 6,000 metres (20,000 ft) deep in the upper crust in the Siljan Ring boreholes and the Kola Superdeep Borehole. Data from the western United States suggests that aquifers from near the surface may extend to depths of 10,000 metres (33,000 ft) to 20,000 metres (66,000 ft). Hydrogen gas can be created by water reacting with silicates, quartz, and feldspar at temperatures in the range of 25 °C (77 °F) to 270 °C (518 °F). These minerals are common in crustal rocks such as granite. Hydrogen may react with dissolved carbon compounds in water to form methane and higher carbon compounds.
> - **Serpentinite mechanism**: n 1967, the Soviet scientist Emmanuil B. Chekaliuk proposed that petroleum could be formed at high temperatures and pressures from inorganic carbon in the form of carbon dioxide, hydrogen and/or methane.
>   This mechanism is supported by several lines of evidence which are accepted by modern scientific literature. This involves synthesis of oil within the crust via catalysis by chemically reductive rocks. A proposed mechanism for the formation of inorganic hydrocarbons is via natural analogs of the Fischer–Tropsch process known as the serpentinite mechanism or the serpentinite process.

Comment: When the essence of the question is literally the title of the Wikipedia article, you should vote to close, optionally downvote the question, and provide a link to the Wikipedia article in a comment. I see no practical purpose of duplicating the summary of a Wikipedia article. You may notice that less than 5% of this answer is original, the rest is copied verbatim.

Comment: As a matter of style, when quoting Wikipedia you should attribute the quotation by using the [permanent link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Abiogenic_petroleum_origin&oldid=1145674624) to the article quoted instead of the live link. Wikipedia articles are living entities, they change in unpredictable ways, and a future reader may not find the quoted words in the unknown future version of the article.

Comment: @AlexP, with the not so irrelevant difference that when you post the link as comment, the OP gets the answer and you get around the quality checks around answer, while here you were allowed to give your downvote.